# How is the user tied to an event/place check-in?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I can't figure out how a user is related to a specific checkin to a place or event.

It looks like no user information is being passed to the checkin endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, no user information is associated with a checkin. A checkin increases the likelihood that the same place or event will show up the next time a search happens for your application.